# Telerik asp.net for MVC kendoui grid

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Does anybody know how I can present a "mail:to" option for an email link in a Telerik grid?

I cannot find anything on the web that redirects to a "mailto" link.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Website).Width(300).Filterable(false).Sortable(false).ClientTemplate("<ahref='#=Website#'>#=Website#</a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing a space if I understand your problem correctly.

```
...ClientTemplate("<a href='mailto:you@you.com'>Mail me</a>");
```

If you need to dynamically create the target, this article has more details:
[How do I use action links?](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-action-links?)